# What is the interface that connects the TV LED screen to the PCB

Tags: led, hdmi, tv

WHile this may be a rather open question, I see that most TV's expose a HDMI port. The HDMI port connects to something that runs linux which in turn connects to the LED screen. What is the interface between the LED screen and the PCB called? How is it generally done?

This picture may help:(I coudnt not find an exact one, but basically what is that flat cable interface? IS it different from on TV to another?)

[image]

Comment: It might be [FPD-Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPD-Link), or it could be a (possibly proprietary) encoding on top of [LVDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling) (LVDS is a physical layer specification). And yes, it may be different between TVs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's all kinds of different connection schemes (manufacturers like to lock you in). Tye most common ones are parallel (D.P.I.) which is just a data line for each bit of colour data (eg. 8 lanes for green, 8 for red etc.) and LVDS (FPD link? among others) which wraps up all the important data into a block and sends the block out over, I think 7, high speed lanes (which can sometimes be paralleled up to run higher resolution displays). Both of these also don't have standardised pinouts or cables, there's 20pin, 30pin, 40pin lcd cables carrying all kinds of formats (there's also DSI, which is mainly found in tablets and smartphones, embedded display port is sometimes used as well). Sorry if this just rasies further questions, but there really is a whole slew of different connection methods.